# Sequelize [ES6] Separate files circular reference

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, sequelize.js

There are two files, one called

***customer.model.js***

```
import DbContext from '../databaseContext'
import Sequelize from 'sequelize'
import LeaseModel from './lease.model';

const CustomerModel = DbContext.define('customer', {
  first_name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING(50)
  },
  middle_name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  last_name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING(50)
  },
  email: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING(62)
  }
})

CustomerModel.hasMany(LeaseModel)


export default CustomerModel
```

***lease.model.js***

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize'

const LeaseModel = DbContext.define('lease', {
  lease_name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING(50)
  },
  customer_id: {
    type: Sequelize.IndexHints
  }
})

export default LeaseModel
```

If I add the following `Lease.belongsTo(CustomerModel)` to ***lease.model.js*** to indicate foreign key relationship I will get circular reference what is the good way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sequelize`  used to have a method called import. You can just import you models there and join each model inside it's constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Create an `index.js` file. Import all models in this file and associate them. After this, re-export these models.

E.g.

`models/customer.model.js`:

```js
import DbContext from '../databaseContext'
import Sequelize from 'sequelize'

const CustomerModel = DbContext.define('customer', {
  first_name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING(50)
  },
  middle_name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  last_name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING(50)
  },
  email: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING(62)
  }
});

export default CustomerModel;
```

`models/lease.model.js`:

```js
import Sequelize from 'sequelize'
import DbContext from '../databaseContext'

const LeaseModel = DbContext.define('lease', {
  lease_name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING(50)
  },
  customer_id: {
    type: Sequelize.IndexHints
  }
})

export default LeaseModel
```

`models/index.js`:

```js
import CustomerModel from './customer.model'
import LeaseModel from './lease.model';
// import other models...

CustomerModel.hasMany(LeaseModel);
LeaseModel.belongsTo(CustomerModel);
// associate other models...

export {CustomerModel, LeaseModel}
```

Comment: interesting, my only challenge is that there could be 100 tables and those relationships will ad up

Comment: @eugenekgn This is the method I used in combination with typescript in the project. I have 30 tables more or less.