# Avoiding cyclic dependencies when using Sequelize with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

I wanted to create a proper setup with Sequelize and TypeScript but hit a roadblock. [The official docs](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/typescript/) show all examples in the same file, thus they have no issues, but when I try to create models in separate files and reference them in the TS typings, I am hit with cyclic dependencies:

```js
// User.ts

import { Guide } from '.';

export class User extends Model<InferAttributes<User>, InferCreationAttributes<User>> {
  declare id: CreationOptional<string>;
  // more attributes...

  declare guides?: NonAttribute<Guide>;
}

User.init(...);

// Guide.ts

import { User } from '.';

export class Guide extends Model<InferAttributes<Guide>, InferCreationAttributes<Guide>> {
  declare id: CreationOptional<string>;
  // more attributes

  declare author_id: NonAttribute<User['id']>;
  declare author?: NonAttribute<User>;

}

Guide.init(...);
```

As you can see, I need to reference `Guide` in `User` and vice-versa for correct typings. Am I missing something obvious? Is there a best-practice approach for this?
There are also issues with calling association methods that stem from the problem above.

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is a `Many-To-Many` association. This needs is a *junction model* to eliminate cyclic dependencies. Say, a `GuideUser` model that has references to both. This way `User`, for example, does not reference `Guide` directly.

https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/#many-to-many-relationships

The junction model can also express a `One-To-Many` association:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity

> An associative (or junction) table maps two or more tables together by referencing the primary keys (PK) of each data table. In effect, it contains a number of foreign keys (FK), each in a many-to-one relationship from the junction table to the individual data tables.

Comment: It's a one-to-many association.

Comment: A one-to-many association can be expressed via the junction table.

Comment: So the answer is to always use junction tables? It's quite astonishing that the docs do not mention anything about this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Examples on https://sequelize.org/ are unhelpful and helpful at the same time. The way to do it is to have everything in the same file, or better, like it's [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62526487/250838)